# How can I make a map of parent structs in go?

Tags: go, go-map

I'm coming from Java/Kotlin so I'm a bit new to the composition-over-inheritance world that Go is in :)

So in Java, I could make a

`abstract class Pet`

and a subclass

```
class Dog extends Pet
class Cat extends Pet
```

and then make a

```
Map<String, Pet> mapOfPets = HashMap();
mapOfPets.put("puppy",  new Dog());
mapOfPets.put("kitty",  new Cat());
```

---

From here, I'm trying to do the equivalent in Golang. Here's how my attempt is going

```
struct Pet{
 // ...
}
struct Dog{
  Pet
}
struct Cat{
  Pet
}
func () {
  petMap := make(map[string]*Pet)

  //invalid
  petMap["puppy"] = &Dog{ ... } 
  petMap["kitty"] = &Cat{ ... }

  // valid
  puppy2 := &Dog{ ... }
  kitty2 := &Cat{ ... }
  petMap["puppy2"] = &puppy2.Pet
  petMap["kitty2"] = &kitty2.Pet
}()
```

I know the **valid** portion of the code should work, but I'm losing the content within the Dog and Cat class. How should I model the map and/or structs for me to be able to make something similar to the **invalid** portion of the code?

It'd be annoying creating a map for each of the 'subclasses' (which I know is the incorrect term here)

PS: any articles or guides on how I should be doing composition would be greatly appreciated too!

Thank you!

Comment: "How I should be doing composition" reminds me of [How to draw an owl](https://memeguy.com/photos/images/how-to-draw-an-owl-363358.png). It's not really a tangible question. Since there is no alternative in Go (like inheritance), it's the same as asking "How to program in Go?" It may be helpful to forget about embedding for a while. It looks like inheritance in OO languages and is often misleading for newcomers, and it can be replaced by writing just a little bit more code in most cases: https://play.golang.org/p/TMF6jWsKwLn

Comment: Don't think about "subclasses", inheritance, or type hierarchies; there are none. Don't try to do a Java "equivalent" in Go, the languages are not equivalent. If you're writing in Go, you need to design for Go; if you design for Java and write in Go you're going to run into endless issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using *interfaces* for this. Your map would be `map[string]Pet`, where `Pet` is:

```
type Pet interface {
  // methods an implementer of Pet should have
}
```

Then your concrete types (`Dog` etc.) would implement the `Pet` interface by having the right methods.

For more information on interfaces, see the [Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/methods/9), [gobyexample](https://gobyexample.com/interfaces) etc. Interfaces will be described extensively in any introductory guide to Go.